# Trying to get a member's status

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now I am doing it on_ready just to try and figure it out.. the status is returning "offline" when i am online.. Ultimately I am looking to do this within a looped task where i check whether they are afk every so often.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mL1R.jpg is my settings in the discord dev portal

Anyway, any ideas where i messed up?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import json

with open('variables.json') as f:
  variables = json.load(f)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ["!", "+", "-"], case_insensitive=True, intents= intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    guild = await client.fetch_guild(796815848219476019)
    user = await guild.fetch_member(118900492607684614)
    print(user.status)

client.run(variables["TOKEN"])
```

Answer (score 1):

So using `get_guild` and then `get_member` did it, but still weird how `fetch` didn't work out :/

Another odd issue is that I can't use `get_member` when using `fetch_guild`, but i can do the inverse of that.  Anyway I got it. For anyone that may stumble across this same issue, here is the resulting code.

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import json

with open('variables.json') as f:
  variables = json.load(f)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ["!", "+", "-"], case_insensitive=True, intents= intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    # guild = await client.fetch_guild(796815848219476019)
    # user = await guild.fetch_member(118900492607684614)
    guild = client.get_guild(796815848219476019)
    print(guild)
    user = guild.get_member(118900492607684614)
    print(user.status)

client.run(variables["TOKEN"])```
````